# LINQ, Large filter on a query

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq

I am building a section of an application that revolves around pulling information about transactions out of the database.  Due to the nature of the data, there are many columns in the table that I want to filter on.  I have a filter selection box with 15 fields that I want to be able to build up a where clause for the LINQ statement.  The interesting part comes when I want certain fields to be null.  For example I want to be able to filter on any or all of:

- Transaction Type
- Response Code
- Transaction Amount
- Many more

I can build up a predicate that looks like

```
Func<Transaction, bool> pred = t => t.ResponseCode == ResponseCode && t.TransactionType == TransactionType && t.TransactionAmount > 100.00;
```

But in order to be able to choose which fields to include in the predicate I am [concatenating the predicates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/491780/concatenating-lambda-functions-in-c) together:

```
Func<Transaction, bool> pred = t => true;
if(ResponseCode != null)
   pred.AndAlso(t => t.ResponseCode == ResponseCode);
// Rinse and repeat
```

And then passing that predicate to the where clause of the LINQ statement.

This works exactly the way I want it, but is rather complicated.  Are there any other ways of doing this?

UPDATE:
Thanks Justice for the comments.  I'm not using LINQ to SQL, I'm using LINQ on a collection of objects from a repository.  How would you programatically build an Expression filter?

Comment: If you're using LinqToObjects (methods on System.Linq.Enumerable), you don't need to worry about Expression<Func<T, bool>>.  Instead use Func<T, bool>.

Comment: I thought you were using LINQ to SQL based on you talking about pulling data from a database.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

- In dynamic SQL...  Since you only have one WHERE clause - you must concatenate predicates with AND.
- In linq query construction... you get as many WHERE clauses as you want.  Linq will AND them together for you when it translates the query.

Example:

```
IQueryable<Transaction> query = db.Transactions;

if (filterByTransactionType)
{
  query = query.Where(t => t.TransactionType == theTransactionType);
}
if (filterByResponseCode)
{
  query = query.Where(t => t.ResponseCode == theResponseCode);
}
if (filterByAmount)
{
  query = query.Where(t => t.TransactionAmount > theAmount);
}
```

Another Example:

```
List<Expression<Func<Transaction, bool>>> filters = GetFilterExpressions();

IQueryable<Transaction> query = db.Transactions;
filters.ForEach(f => query = query.Where(f));
```

Answer (score 0):

First, you would need to use `Expression<Func<Transaction, bool>>` for LINQ-to-SQL (that's what you're trying to use, and it's not the same thing as LINQ).

Second, you can programmatically build up an `Expression<Func<Transaction, bool>>` using the `System.Linq.Expression` namespace.

You will not be able to use LINQ per se to query the database using programmatically built-up expressions. Instead of using the query operators, you will need to use the query extension methods: for example, instead of `from p in db.People where p.Age > 50 select p.Name` you will need to use `db.People.Where(p => p.Age > 50)`. You can use this style to add filters: `db.People.Where(myFilter)`, where `myFilter = new Expression<Func<Person, bool>>(p => p.Age > 50)`. In your case, `myFilter` would be your programmatically built-up filter, not one created using lambda-expression syntax.