# Linq to custom sql

Tags: c#, sql, linq, linq-to-sql

Okay so I have a db with a HUGE table.  Over 1million records and over 50 columns.  (I know its not optimal but its what I have to work with)  So I need to run queries that limit the amount of data returned.  Now my problem is this.  I have some custom queries that run and return data.  The user can filter that data down more by selecting filter and options that will generate a Predicate template and applies it to the list.  I now need to take the list of predicates and Combine them and re-query the db to search for (changes or other entries matching).  The problem is this

```
private Func<table,bool> filterAll()
    {

        Func<table, bool> temp = null;
        var list = mylist.filterList; //filterlist is a list<Predicate<table>>
        var list2 = list.Select(val => val.Value).ToArray();

        foreach(var a in list2)
        {

            temp += t => a(t);
        }
        return temp;
    }

    private void loadWithFiltersButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {


        var temp = db.table.Where(filterAll());

    }
```

I cant turn the predicates into a usable sql query.  I get an exception saying it is unable to generate the sql for the list of Predicates.  I have also tried this

```
Func<table, bool> query1 = temp2 => temp2.Name.Contains("test string");
Func<table, bool> query2 = temp2 => temp2.ignore == false;
var temp = db.table.Where(query1);
var myval = temp.Where(temp2 => temp2.Name.Contains("test string")).Select(val => val).ToList();
```

And while that does execute the problem is the sql generated pull down the whole table and doesnt generate a where clause at all.

I have been searching and found this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/974719/how-to-use-linq-to-compile-a-lambda-expression-to-custom-sql-or-otherwise  but all the links people posted in the answers are dead for me.

So basicly how can I combine multiple predicates into a usable query that will have the db return the least amount of data possible?

Edit:  Tried this also [Concatenating Lambda Functions in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/491780/concatenating-lambda-functions-in-c-sharp) but it also throws the exception that sql query cannot be generated.

Comment: Use `Expression<Func<table, bool>>`.

Comment: That works when I do the second part.  The thing is my main issue is I have a list of Predicates that I need to combine and execute.  How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

Try using

```
SqlMethods.Like(temp2.Name, "test string")
```

instead of:

```
temp2.Name.Contains("test string")
```

In order to do so, you must add the reference:

```
System.Data.Linq.SqlClient
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have a new `List<Expression<System.Func<table, bool>>>` rather than a new `List<System.Func<table, bool>>` then you can do something like

```
private void Test()
{
   var list = new List<Expression<System.Func<table, bool>>>();

    Expression<Func<table, bool>> query1 = temp2 => temp2.Name.Contains("test string");
    Expression<Func<table, bool>> query2 = temp2 => temp2.ignore == false;

    list.Add(query1);
    list.Add(query2);

    var temp = filterAll(list).ToList();
}


private System.Linq.IQueryable<table> filterAll(List<Expression<Func<table, bool>>> list2 )
{

    var query = table.AsQueryable();
    foreach (var a in list2)
    {
        query = query.Where(a);
    }
    return query;
}
```