# Linq-to-sql user generated predicate

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql

Background:  I have a huge table many columns and many entries in a db.  I have some preset queries that return data but I need the ability to let the user further refine the query (add more filters).

So my question is I have code as follows:

```
var dbquery = (from a in db.test where id > 100 select a);
```

This returns a iQueryable.  Now I can futher filter it (and still have the query run on the db) when i do this

```
var dbquery2 = dbquery.Where(b => b.quanity > 20);
```

But what I really want is for the user to be able to input the filters and have it still run on the db.  I have lookat at PropertyDescriptors but they always say there is no approriate linq to sql translation.
How can I do something like this:

```
var dbqueryuser = dbquery.where(c => c.(user specified field) > 20);
```

Do I need to do custom generated SQL statements or can I somehow generate valid

```
Expression<Func<test,bool>>
```

statements using reflection?

Note:  This is building on a previous question I asked here [Linq to custom sql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40685715/linq-to-custom-sql)

I basicly need to take the filter list but get the queries to run on the db (as the db returns a lot of data and I want to get as much filtered at the db side rather than user side)

Comment: Yes, you can generate `Expression<Func<test,bool>>` dynamically, not with reflection but with `Expression` class methods. There are many examples on SO of doing that, if you want more concrete answer, you should post how your filter definition looks like.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to generate a custom `Expression`, just for example (it won't compile):

```
var param = Expression.Parameter(typeof(Entity));
var property = Expression.PropertyOrField(param, propertyName);
var greater = Expression.GreaterThan(property, Expression.Constant(20));
var lambda = (Expression<Func<Entity, bool>>)Expression.Lambda(greater, param);
```

Comment: Works :)  thanks  How can I do that on properties that are nullable though?  It says there is no greaterthan operator that can compare a Nullable<System.Int32> with System.Int32

Comment: They are not comparable, you should get property Value from nullable, or better, call method "getValueOrDefault" , or read for example hier: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/586097/compare-nullable-types-in-linq-to-sql   there is a lot of stuff about expressions on SO

Comment: Ill look at that :)  thanks  but I did find another solution
            var testnull = Expression.TypeAs(Expression.Constant(20), typeof(Nullable<System.Int32>));
            var greater = Expression.GreaterThan(property,testnull);